# I stuck with jquery stuff for tag boxes while creating dynamically ? anyone knows retrieving data from dynamic created forms

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is my code i dynamically created some forms for tag fields but its not working for newly creating forms and how can i retrieve data from those tags seperately in jquery only please help to solve . First form present in the html body is working properly with tags

```
<style type="text/css">
#tags{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
#tags span.tag{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  background:#689;
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  margin:4px;
}
#tags span.tag:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
#tags span.tag:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"x";
 border:1px solid;
 padding:0 4px;
 margin:3px 0 10px 5px;
 font-size:10px;
}
#tags input{
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
  margin:4px;
  padding:7px;
  width:auto;
}
</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="options">
    <h2 class="heading">Variants</h2>
    <table width="75%" height="150%">
      <tr>
        <td><p>Does this product come in multiple variations like size or color?</p></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="product-options" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add variants"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


      <div id="option_form" class="form-group">
        <table id="options" width="100%" >
          {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'','class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => ''))!!}
         <tr>
            <th width="25%">{!! Form::label('Option name') !!}</th>
            <th>{!! Form::label('Option values') !!}</th>

          </tr>
          <div id="opt"><tr>
            <td>{!! Form::text('opname[]', null, array('class'=>'opname')) !!}</td>
             <td><div id="tags" >{!! Form::text('opvalues[]') !!} </div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">  <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"  type="button" id="remove"  /></a></td>
          </tr></div>

          {!! Form::close() !!}
        </table>
        <input  type="button" id="addOption" value="Add another option" />
      </div><br><br>
      <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="variants-table" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="min-width:50px" class="select"></th>
              <th><span class="options-header">Variant</span></th>
              <th style="min-width:100px"><span>Price</span></th>
              <th style="min-width:100px"><span>SKU</span></th>
              <th style="min-width:100px"><span>Barcode</span></th>
              <th style="min-width:70px" bind-show="inventoryOptions.inventoryManagement"><span>Inventory</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>{!! Form::checkbox('opname[]' ,null, array('checked'=>'true')) !!}</td>
              <td>{!! Form::text('variant[]', null, array('class'=>'variant')) !!}</td>
              <td>{!! Form::text('opname[]') !!}</td>
              <td>{!! Form::text('opname[]') !!}</td>
              <td>{!! Form::text('opname[]') !!}</td>
              <td>{!! Form::text('opname[]') !!}</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>





  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#option_form").hide();
      $("#remove").hide();
      $('#product-options').click(function () {
        var txt = $('#product-options').val()
        if (txt == 'Add variants') {
          $(this).val('Cancel');
          $("#option_form").show();
          return false;
        }
        else if (txt == 'Cancel') {
          $(this).val('Add variants');
          $("#option_form").hide();
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
      var counter = 1;
      jQuery('#addOption').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#remove").show();
        counter++;
        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>{!! Form::text('opname[]') !!}</td><td><div id="tags">{!! Form::text('opvalues[]') !!} </div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" type="button" id="remove"  /></a></td></tr>');
        jQuery('#options').append(newRow);
        if (counter == 3)
                    $("#addOption").hide();
        });
        $("#options").on('click','.remCF',function(){
          $("#addOption").show();
          if(counter>2){
              $(this).parent().parent().remove();
              counter--;
            }else{
               $(this).parent().parent().remove();
               $("#remove").hide();
               counter = 1;
            }

        });
    });

</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

          $('#tags input').on('focusout',function(){    
            var txt= this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g,''); // allowed characters
            if(txt) {
              $(this).before('<span class="tag">'+ txt.toLowerCase() +'</span>');
            }
            this.value="";
          }).on('keyup',function( e ){
            // if: comma,enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
            if(/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) $(this).focusout(); 

          });


          $('#tags').on('click','.tag',function(){
             if(confirm("Really delete this tag?")) $(this).remove(); 
          });

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved just add $(document).on('focusout','.option-values',function() { instead